# where do I put tomcat context.xml data in JBoss EAP 7.0.0?

Tags: java, mysql, xml, jboss

I have an application on Tomcat. It uses mysql for persistence. I define the mysql connection related data in context.xml as follows:

```
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
         on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    -->
    <Resource 
        auth="Container" 
        description="User database that can be updated and saved" 
        name="jdbc/VTREProto" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100" 
        maxIdle="30" 
        maxWait="10000" 
        removeAbandoned="true"
        username="vtreapp" 
        password="vtre!@#$%" 
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/developermodule" 
        />

</Context>
```

I access this in my java code as:

```
    InitialContext initCTX = new InitialContext();
    // Lookup the DataSource, which will be backed by a pool
    //   that the application server provides.
    pool = (DataSource)initCTX.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/VTREProto");
```

I want to migrate to JBoss EAP 7.0.0. how and where do I specify the above resource in JBoss EAP 7.0.0 without breaking my java code.

Thanx and regards

Answer (score 0):

In JBoss you don't need a context.xml. 
You only need to create a datasource in configuration file: (standalone.xml or domain.xml) accordingly to the mode you are running JBoss.

I suggest you change the jndi name as well to the default "java:jboss/datasources/VTREProto" for example. Instead of "java:comp/env/jdbc/VTREProto".

An example of mysql datasource :

```
<datasources>
  <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/VTREProto" pool-name="VTREProtoDS">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jbossdb</connection-url>
    <driver>mysql</driver>
    <security>
      <user-name>admin</user-name>
      <password>admin</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
      <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
      <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
      <background-validation>false</background-validation>
      <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
    </validation>
</datasource>
```

More details on [official documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-jboss-enterprise-application-platform/7.0/paged/configuration-guide/chapter-13-datasource-management).

Comment: It is very good answer. But how do I migrate an Environment element from context.xml (Tomcat) to Wildfly or any JBoss application server?

Comment: @Chase _<Parameter>_ in tomcat can be migrated to jboss as _<property>_. For example - 
`<properties>
        <property name="myrepodir" value="C:\Windows\myuser\proj1\repo"/>
    </properties>`  OR  
`<system-properties>
        <property name="myrepodir" value="C:\Windows\myuser\proj1\repo"/>
    </system-properties>`